# Applying KVL to a grounded MOSFET circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, homework, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm rather confused as to how to how this circuit doesn't violate KVL:
[image]

The two node voltages on the right side of the loop add to -4.16V, which means the voltages on the left should add to 4.16V, right? But there's only one node on the left side and that's grounded.

My initial thought was that there's really two loops, that the NMOS connection on the left makes another node and another loop. But if that were the case, it shouldn't be showing 0V at the top. And anyway, for an ideal MOSFET, no current should be going from gate to drain or gate to source at all, and certainly not when the gate is only connected to ground. So what am I missing here? How does this circuit not violate KVL?

To be extra clear, what's really confusing me is that there seem to be only three nodes total, two of them with negative voltages, and the third one is grounded and hence has zero volts, rather than the absolute value of the sum of the other two nodes (so that the total loop voltage is zero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For KVL, we should not add the node voltages. We need to add the voltage across the components in the loop.

Here, when you go around the loop in counter-clockwise direction, you have a -2V voltage across the voltage source, -0.16V across the current source and +2.16V across the NMOS VGS. The respective polarities are shown in the edited image below. So, if you add all the 3 voltage drops, it will zero. This is the correct interpretation of KVL.

[image]